# Dynamic key value type

Tags: ios, swift

I have a json that I decode using Codable.

```
struct Item: Codable {
    let data: Data // dictionary or array
}

struct Data: Codable {
    let id: Int
}
```

The "data" field can be an array or a dictionary.

How do I decode my json ?

[example json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqZLs.png)

Comment: @Olympiloutre You are wrong, this format is actually quite common and `Any` can be avoided.

Comment: @Sulthan totally right I was working on it right now. Didn't see the "type" associated I thought it was just random datas that could either be an array or a dict. My bad !

Comment: How would the `id` be extracted in both cases? I assume for dictionary is pretty obvious, but what about the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to decode `data` depending on `type`. That means you have to first decode `type` and then continue depending on its value.
Usually to store such items we would use an `enum` with associated values:

```
enum Item: Decodable {
    case onboarding(OnboardingData)
    case entry(EntryData)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)

        switch type {
        case "onboarding":
            let data = try container.decode(OnboardingData.self, forKey: .data)
            self = .onboarding(data)
        case "entry":
            let data = try container.decode(EntryData.self, forKey: .data)
            self = .entry(data)
        default:
            throw DecodingError.unknownType
        }
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type
        case data
    }

    private enum DecodingError: String, Error {
        case unknownType
    }
}

struct OnboardingData: Decodable {
}

struct EntryData: Decodable {
}
```

`OnboardingData` and `EntryData` are just type placeholders. You can change them to anything to want, e.g. an array of items. Also, you might wrap arrays inside them.

Comment: The "type" field has many values. Not only "onboarding" and "entry"

Comment: This solution is not suitable for this json. Since all the values of the type field are not known

Comment: @ИгорьСазонов What exactly is not suitable? Do you want to only parse the values you know and skip the others?

Comment: No. I want to parse all the values. But I don't know all the values of the "type" field.

Comment: @ИгорьСазонов The `type` fields are part of the JSON format. You cannot parse JSON if you don't know the format.

Comment: @Sulthan that's what I thought yesterday (guess the question was edited). It's achievable if he knows what's in the array or dictionnary (e.g. its either an array of `[Type]` or a dictionnary of `[String:Type]` idk), by try catching to decode it as an array, then falling into decoding it as a dictionnary... 
See now why I was so categorical haha